# Обращение к поисковику программно

Tags: c#

Как программно обращаться к поисковику google, ya и др, осуществить поиск по ключевым словам и сохранить, к примеру, первые 10 страниц?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Google есть API поиска

- [Google Web Search API](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/websearch/docs/) (устаревший)
- [JSON/Atom Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html)

Для устаревшего как-то

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    var query = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q={0}&key=customkey";
    var keyword = "something";

    wc.Headers.Add("Referrer", "http://localhost/");
    var result = wc.DownloadString(String.Format(query, keyword));
}
```

Comment: Поподробнее можно я просто не сталкивался с этим??

Answer (score 2):

тут в двух словах не ответишь.
Нужно послать запрос с помощью класса  HttpWebRequest, получить ответ и разобрать его, например, с помощью регулярных выражений. Для того чтобы понять как его разбирать - нужно сначала глазами изучить ответ поисковика для поиска закономерностей, по которым можно выделить результаты. Этот подход касается не только поисковика, но и любого веб-сервера.

Кроме этого, поисковик может открывать отдельный доступ для программ в виде веб-сервиса. В этом случае запрос-ответ посылается как правило в виде XML и разбор его гораздо проще. Есть ли такой сервис - зависит от поисковика, нужно изучать документацию для разработчиков, предоставляемую поисковым сервером.